# How do little kids ask for stories in English?

Tags: errors

How would little, native English speaking kids say "Tell me a story about the bear!"?  In my language, they might say something like "Tell me the bear!". Does "Tell me the bear!" sounds like a valid "little English" question from a little kid who is catching up the language?

Context:

Each language has different logic, and the kids build up the logic differently. I am very much curious about how young kids in native English environment build up the logic of the English language. For example, in my language, they might say something like "Tell me the bear!" instead of "Tell me the story about the bear!" Do English-speaking kids make similar mistakes, like saying "Tell me the bear"? What are the common mistakes they make in this context?

Comment: Very little children will probably use what is known as 'conversational deletion' when done consciously: "Story! [please]" "Three bears!" Then "I want a story." "A new one" a little later (though story-telling is probably mainly parent-driven in today's electronic age. Then, a mere title or keyword will suffice.)

Comment: I think this is a fair question, but you might get close-voters saying this is opinion-based. It could help if you added some details or narrowed your question.

Comment: ... It's possibly on the wrong site. I'm not sure whether 'Language Learning' or 'Interpersonal Skills' might be more appropriate.

Comment: Tell me the one, again, about the girl and the bear food…you know.

Comment: What do you mean by "**little**, native English speaking kids"? As I understand it, and from experience, a child's command of the language changes from first speaking to, say, about three years and then enters another phase to about 6 years. In the first phase, they say anything that comes into their mind.

Comment: I think this is a relevant question about the English language itself. The kids do not make random errors, they make errors that inherit from the hidden structure of the language. For non-native speakers or speakers without being exposed to kids it is not possible to know these errors, but knowing them would reveal a lot about the beauty of the language. I understand though if the community considers is as off-topic.